# Print Cell Text from TableView into new viewController UILabel (swift)

Tags: swift

So my goal is when the cell is selected to take the textLabel inside the cell and print it in the new ViewControllers UILabel.

I already have it set up to where when the cell is selected it pushed to the new View Controller.  I just can't figure out how to get it to print the cell textLabel into the UILabel of the new ViewController.

Here is my Code for the TableView but what should I write to retrieve the cell textLabel into my new ViewController?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPostContent") as! showPostContent

    print(currentCell.textLabel?.text)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Try "secondViewController.FooBar = "some string" " Where Foobar is a string that you have declared in your secondViewController.

Answer (score 2):

As far I can see in your question you're trying to pass data from one controller to another. In your case you can use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method when the cell is tapped as you did and just set your value to the `UILabel` in your `secondViewController` or you can set a push segue for the cell to the next controller and in the `prepareForSegue` pass the data you need.

> **Case 1:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
   let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPostContent") as! showPostContent
   // this line call the loadView method to avoid the IBOutlet is not nil
   let _ = secondViewController.view

   // pass the data
   secondViewController.NameOfYourUILabelOutlet.text = currentCell.textLabel?.text

   print(currentCell.textLabel?.text)
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

> **Case 2:**

After you set the segue in your Storyboard:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NameOfYourViewController
    let _ = destinationViewController.view

    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }

    let indexOfCellSelected = indexPath.row
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    destinationViewController.NameOfYourUILabelOutlet.text = cell.NameOfYourUILabelOutlet.text
}
```

In case you don't want to call the `view` property to instantiate the `@IBOulet` you can create a property set the value for it and then in the `viewDidLoad` set the value for the `@IBOulet` inside it.

I hope this help you.